# We planned to create an e-commence website using react, back end PHP, MYSQL. How to maintain cart session and user session values in reacting JS?

Tags: reactjs

We planned to create an Ecommence website using react, back end PHP, MYSQL. How to maintain cart session and user session values in reacting JS?

Answer (score 1):

I reccomend using jtoker. It provides all aspects of authentication required for a standard web application. You will need to configure your backend a bit to work properly with it, but it leverages fairly high standards in terms of security.

You can read more here

[J-Toker Github](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/j-toker)

From there, I reccomend using redux with react to manage global state, and on application init, use j-toker for check for the existence of a user token, and if it exists load the user information from localstorage into global state.